# autoloading for namespaced classes, php

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I have a custom algorithm to load classes. There are `$sourcePaths`-es, the autoloader looks all .php files in that, and collect classes, interfaces from the files. It then stores in an associative array `$classes[class name] => absoule path`. Later, when autoload occurs, it looks if the class is in the array, if not that class doesnt exists.
So far its OK. But here comes the namespaces. Lets see an namespace `Doctrine\ORM\Query;` and a class `Parameter { .... }` case. First simply I handled it as it was Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter ... so namespace+class name. But then theres an `new Query\Parameter` this still wont be found. Whats is the correct algorithm for finding classes inside namespaces?

The classes collecting:

```
foreach ($sourcePaths as $dir)
{
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $fileinfo)
    {
        if (substr($fileinfo->getFilename(), -4) == '.php')
        {
            $absPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $dir.'/'.$fileinfo->getFilename());
            foreach (getPhpClasses($absPath) as $item)
            {
                $autoloadClassPaths[$item] = $absPath;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this function gets the stuffs out from the php code:

```
function getPhpClasses ($filename)
{
    $output = array();
    $namespace = '';
    $tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents($filename));
    for ($i = 2; $i < sizeof($tokens); $i++)
    {
        if (($tokens[$i - 2][0] == T_NAMESPACE) && $tokens[$i - 1][0] == T_WHITESPACE && $tokens[$i][0] == T_STRING)
        {
            $j = 0;
            do
            {
                $namespace .= $tokens[$i + $j][1];
                $j++;
            } while ($tokens[$i + $j] != ';');
            $namespace .= '\\';
        }

        if (($tokens[$i - 2][0] == T_CLASS || $tokens[$i - 2][0] == T_INTERFACE) && $tokens[$i - 1][0] == T_WHITESPACE && $tokens[$i][0] == T_STRING)
        {
            $output[] = $namespace.$tokens[$i][1];
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your implementation of autoload?

Comment: yea right, question is edited

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to organize the code, so you wouldn't have to scan all sources looking for classes, but simply change namespace to path and load it? See https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md